# ORBEON.xforms.Document.setValue getValue dispatchEvent how to use?

Tags: orbeon

I have tried this on Orbeon 4.6 and 4.7.

ORBEON.xforms.Document.setValue, getValue or DispatchEvents commands throw error dialogs when called.

Appreciate if someone has had any luck in getting these to work.

Please see a snipet below of the xhtml, when I run this the alert message displays "undefined" when it should have displayed "42", if I change the getValue() to setValue() and pass the name and value as parameters the system returns an error :

```
<xf:instance id="fr-form-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
<form>
    <section-1>
        <control-1/>
        <foo>42</foo>
        <bar/>
    </section-1>
</form>
</xf:instance>

.......
<xh:td>
<xf:input id="control-1-control" bind="control-1-bind">
    <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-1/label"/>
    <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-1/hint"/>
    <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
</xf:input>
<xf:input ref="foo" id="foo">
    <xf:label class="fixed-width">Value of foo:</xf:label>
</xf:input>
<xf:output ref="bar">
    <xf:label class="fixed-width">Value of bar:</xf:label>
</xf:output>
<xf:trigger>
    <xf:label>JavaScript</xf:label>
    <xxf:script ev:event="DOMActivate">
        alert(ORBEON.xforms.Document.getValue("foo"));

    </xxf:script>
</xf:trigger>
</xh:td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't working because you need to use the id as it is in the HTML, and the id in the HTML is different from the control name in 2 ways:

1. Form Builder adds `-control` at the end of the name to produce the id.
2. Because with Form Runner the control is inside XBL components, the id of those components in prefixed to the id of the control.

Because of this, if your control is named `my-control` in  Form Builder, I'd recommend you use the following to get its value in JavaScript:

```
var control = ORBEON.jQuery('*[id $= "my-control-control"]');
var value = ORBEON.xforms.Document.getValue(control.attr('id'));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into this issue. I tried as you suggested but now I get the client error saying that ORBEON.jquery is invalid command. I also tried changing the ID but still no luck, in my example above the input control "foo" has the id of "foo" is that incorrect then? This example is copied straight from the tutorials so I am unsure as to what I am doing wrong. Perhaps I am on an older release of Orbeon (4.6)? I really do not want to go through an upgrade but if it can be confirmed that this is the issue then I would gladly do that.

Comment: @KJ1982 Yes, sorry, I should have mentioned this: if you're using a version before 4.10, use `$` instead of `ORBEON.jQuery`. The need to use `ORBEON.jQuery` is something new in 4.10, as we don't "populate" anymore the global namespace, which allows people to have their own version of jQuery for other things they might want to do on the page.